# Help with the following linq query?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Take the following linq query:

```
var summary = results.Select(r => 
                             new
                             {
                             TotalPopulation = results.Sum(s => s.Population),
                             TotalGross = results.Sum(s => s.Gross),
                             }).Distinct();
```

The above works fine, but is it the best way to do it.  What does the r represent?  Why do I need it?

Also,  I would think that I could add the following to my query, but I can't:

```
GrossPerPop = TotalPopulation / TotalGross
```

The above says TotalPopulation and Total Gross do not exist in the current context.

I also tried:

```
GrossPerPop = results.sum(s => s.Population) / results.Sum(s => s.Gross),
```

The above says / can't be applied to decimal? or double?   Does this have anything to do with the fields being nullable?  It just so happens I don't have any Population fields or Gross fields with a null value, so I changed these to non-nullable fields in the sql table designer.  However, if they do contain a 0 value, how could I check that within the Linq code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way is something like:

```
class Metrics {
    public int TotalPopulation { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalGross { get; set; }
    public decimal GrossPerPopulation {
        get {
            return TotalGross / TotalPopulation;
        }
    }
 }
```

Then:

```
var metrics = new Metrics {
                  TotalPopulation = results.Sum(s => s.Population), 
                  TotalGross = results.Sum(s => s.Gross)
              };
```

What you currently have is performing the above projection (albeit into an anonymous type) for every element of `results` and then throwing out all but one of the resulting projections. You could get by without creating an explicit type as I've done above and just use an anonymous type but that would be silly.

> What does the `r` represent?

The `r` represents the name of the parameter in the anonymous method that you've defined.

> Why do I need it?

When you write

```
results.Select(expression)
```

it is necessary that `expression` be a delegate that eats whatever the type of the  elements of `results` are and returns some other type. That is `IEnumerable<SomeType>.Select` is for projecting a sequenece to another sequence. Therefore, you must pass a method that eats whatever the type of the elements of `results` are and returns some other type. One way of doing is that is by passing in an anonymous delegate. One way of defining an anonymous delegate is by using a lambda expression. When you say `r => ...` you are defining an anonymous method via a lambda expression.

> Also, I would think that I could add the following to my query, but I can't:
>
> `GrossPerPop = TotalPopulation / TotalGross`

That's right, you can't. Think of it like this. Say that you had an explicit type

```
class Metrics {
    public int TotalPopulation { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalGross { get; set; }
    public decimal GrossPerPopulation { get; set; }
    public Metrics(
        int totalPopulation,
        decimal totalGross,
        decimal grossPerPopulation
    ) {
            TotalPopulation = totalPopulation;
            TotalGross = totalGross;
            GrossPerPopulation = grossPerPopulation;
    }
}
```

Should the following be legal?

```
Metrics m = new Metrics(100, 100, m.TotalPopulation / m.TotalGross)
```

Of course not! But that's effectively what you are trying to do.

> `GrossPerPop = results.Sum(s => s.Population) / results.Sum(s => s.Gross)`
>
> The above says `/` can't be applied to decimal? or double?

I don't see any reason for you to be getting such a message. In C#, the above is legal assuming that both `s.Population` and `s.Gross` are numeric types; they will just be implicitly promoted to the "right" type. This is true even if `s.Population` or `s.Gross` are numeric types.

Do note however that gross per population should be

```
results.Sum(s => s.Gross) / results.Sum(s => s.Population)
```

Comment: Thanks, it is still a bit confusing, but I am trying.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I quickly tried Andreys' code, but I am getting an error regarding it.  I put it in the comments. Do you know the reason?

Comment: Because the result of his code is not an object that implements `IEnumerable`, `IListSource` nor `IDataSouce`. You could bind `new[] { summary }`.

Comment: I tried   var summary = new[]
        {
            TotalPopulation = results.Sum(s => s.Population),
            TotalGross = results.Sum(s => s.Gross),
        };

but it says TotalPopulation, TotalGross are not recognized.

Comment: I implemented your code above and I got the same error message saying:

Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource. 

I am trying to bind Metrics to a datasource.

Comment: No, you would need to say `var summary = new[] { new Metrics { TotalPopulation = results.Sum(s => s.Population), TotalGross = results.Sum(s => s.Gross) } };`

Comment: Both answers work, so which is the better one?  Are there any pros an cons?

Answer (score 2):

It is not good query because Sum will be calculated for every row and then it will be "distinct"ed.

Just write

```
var summary = new
   {
      TotalPopulation = results.Sum(s => s.Population),
      TotalGross = results.Sum(s => s.Gross),
   };
```

Comment: yeah, can you explain the distinct to me? I put it on there because I was getting multiple rows and I was curious if I actually needed the r =>

Comment: I tried your code above and I am binding summary to a datasource, but now I am getting the error:

Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.

Comment: Your final goal is to show TotalPopulation and TotalGross? So it is single values, i am not sure why to bind them to datasource. if you want that much put my code into new[] { mycodehere };

Comment: I am binding the values returned into summary into to a GridView.

Comment: I added the new[], ut now it says TotalPopulation does not exist in the current context.

Comment: new[] { new {TotalPopulation = results.Sum(s => s.Population), TotalGross = results.Sum(s => s.Gross) } };